# how to show list in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to show list in angular 2. I am getting template parsing error.
I added this component

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {TodoService} from "./todo-service";
@Component({
    selector: 'todo-list',
    template: `<div>
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="#t of todoService.todos">
            {{t}}
          </li>
         /ul>
       </div>`
})
export class TodoList {
  constructor(public todoService: TodoService) {}
}
```

try to display list. But getting this error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>       Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 7 in [ngFor #t of todoService.todos] in TodoList@2:21 ("

Here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/FvdcxQoa5PCp0jx1tNgO?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/tKMzJzlr0Zd6zSd5bHsX?p=preview

You just need to change **#** to **let** keyword.

```
<li *ngFor="let t of todoService.todos">
```